# How to support Client Certificate Mutual Authentication with IBM Worklight 6.2 for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

I am very new to Android, but i have been working as a Web Developer for a mobile webapp. and we need to wrap this webapp in a Worklight Android Hybrid App.
We have a mobile webapp that relies on Client Certificate Mutual Authentication for security, using X509 Certificates.

We already have an iOS Hybrid App that does the following:

```
- Check if Certificate is installed
- Redirect to Certificate Repository
- Download Certificate from the Repo
- Install Cert in App KeyChain
- Redirect to Secured WebApp with Client Cert Authentication
```

We have implemented this in iOS by overwriting the UIViewController and creating a CustomHTTPProtocol based on Apple's code: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Listings/Read_Me_About_CustomHTTPProtocol_txt.html, it's a bit large to provide a snippet.

To put it simply: we just want to know how to handle web pages with Client Certificates in Android and WorkLight.
Is it from the MainActivity, CordovaWebView or CordovaWebViewClient? 
We dont want to ignore the certificate like the code from here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/apache_cordova_working_with_certificates_on_android?lang=en

I am digging up all related solutions, but i couldnt find any that will provide an answer.
Maybe i need to handle HttpsURLConnection directly in Android, I'm not sure.

Comment: I suggest you provide a snippet of what you did in iOS so that maybe someone can translate the idea to Android.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. i couldnt provide a snippet since we just based the code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Listings/Read_Me_About_CustomHTTPProtocol_txt.html, it's just handling the certificate by checking if it's in the keychain. it's a bit large and we just modified it. and i wasnt the iOS developer, it was from an old dev who has since left. it just works.

Answer (score 0):

In worklight, you contact your backend via adapters. So from your app you invoke the adapter which then calls the backend. Security etc get handled at the adapter layer. 
So in this type of architecture, you configure Worklight server by defining your keystore (and the cert to use within that keystore). This would be used by the adapter when it tries to contact a backend for which mutual authentication has been configured. And you would add the CA certificate of the backend to the trust store of the app server where Worklight is running on so that Worklight also can authenticate the backend.
So mainly, you need to do the following:

- Use Worklight adapters to contact backend
- Configure Worklight server with Keystore by specifying in worklight.properties or JNDI entries
- Add the CA certificate of the backend to the trust store of App server on which worklight server is running
- Mention the sslCertificateAlias, password etc in Adapter's xml file
- Call this adapter from the app to get to backend

Info on Keystore and SSL configuration to be done in adapter can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_ssl_certificate_keystore_setup.html).

And this approach should work for both Android as well as iOS.